# Docker container network failed Occasionally

Tags: python, linux, docker

I used docker container that using logstash.
But, Sometimes container network failed.

```
=> ping google.co.kr

cannot resolve google.co.kr : Unknown host.
```

This symptom occurs in a week interval, while it works.

**container linux version**

```
Linux 81ed1c4b8bc9 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 03:15:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**docker i/o version**

```
Docker version 1.3.2, build 39fa2fa/1.3.2
```

Wrote additional information , several articles mentioned with `iptables`.

```
[root@81ed1c4b8bc9 opt]# iptables -L
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

I'd really appreciate if anyone could give me a useful advise on how to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: This reminds me of some problems solved by  pinging/accessing regularly a node, for example, your host could ping/access  a port on your container every 5 minutes

Comment: Hmm... 
I think that is incorrectly solution.
Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping via the ip address?

What is the content of /etc/resolv.conf?

If this is true, add dns options to the docker service (eg. --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4)